# Can AWS Lambda python function connect to a SQL Server?

Tags: c#, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on an item whereby a CloudWatch alarm triggers an SNS notification, which in turn triggers an AWS Lambda Function (in Python). I need the function to connect to a SQL server and run a command. I have tried with pyodbc and pypyodbc, and so far no luck. I'm starting to think it won't be possible.

If not possible in Python, can it be done in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 1, 2016, you can now develop AWS Lambda functions in C# using the .NET Core 1.0 runtime. As far as connecting to SQL, you can use entity framework core nuget package or use the SQL Server Database Provider and write a wrapper for it. [See example here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35974.exploring-net-core-net-core-1-0-connecting-sql-server-database.aspx).

I tried creating a C# lambda function (a month ago for developing Alexa skill) when it first became available and published it on AWS but got some error publishing it. I posted this question in SO here: [Error in publishing an AWS Lambda function built in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292599/error-in-publishing-an-aws-lambda-function-built-in-net-core)

So just refer to that link if you get into some publishing errors.